# java script is not working in mozila

Tags: javascript

I have added some javascript in html page for input validation.same page is working correct in IE and chrome but in **mozila** its not working.The problem is when user inputs invalid data its supposed to show **alert msg box** and when user clicks **OK** it should return **false** to form...**BUT** mozila is not waiting for **alert box** it just shows alert box for 5-6 sec and then goes to next page defined in **form action="nextpage.php"**

```
 function validate_form(thisform) 
    {
    with (thisform) 
        {
        if (validate_required(oldpassword, "<b>Error: </b>Please enter the Old Password!") == false)
        { changeColor("oldpassword"); return false; }

        else if (valid_length(newpassword, "<b>Error: </b>Please enter the New Password!!") == false)
        {newpassword.value=""; changeColor("newpassword"); return false; }

        else if (valid_length(cnfpassword, "<b>Error: </b>Please enter the Confirm Password!!") == false)
        {cnfpassword.value=""; changeColor("cnfpassword"); return false; }

        else if (document.getElementById('newpassword').value != document.getElementById('cnfpassword').value)
        {changeColor("newpassword");cool.error("<b>Error: </b>Passwords entered are not same!"); 
        newpassword.value="";cnfpassword.value="";return false;}

    }
}function validate_required(field, alerttxt) 
    {
    with (field) 
        {
        if (value == null || value == "") 
            {
           cool.error(alerttxt);return false;
            }
        else 
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**cool.error** is nothing but CSS nd Js for alert box.I thing there is not any problem in my **code** weather problem is in some browser settings.Is it so??? because it is working fine in **IE** and **Chrome**.

Comment: As a general note here, never assume the bug is **not in your code**, 99.9999% of the time, at least on established platforms, **it is your code**, assuming the opposite will do nothing but waste time finding the cause.

Comment: as another not you may want to look into some jquery validation plugins might save you some time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a non-standard IE-only behavior that creates global variables for every element with an ID.

To fix it, add a global variable for each element that you use:

```
var oldpassword = document.getElementById("oldpassword");
```

Also, you should *never* use Javascript's `with` block.
It is very different from VB's `with` block, and should not be used unless you truly understand its pitfalls and shortcomings.  It will also slow down your code.

Comment: Add lines like `var oldpassword = document.getElementById("oldpassword");` outside of your functions for each HTML Element that you use in Javascript.

Comment: Or `myformobject.elements.oldpassword` if you're using names only. But using IDs is easier.

Comment: Like this???---  
 function validate_form(thisform) 
  {
   var oldpassword = document.getElementById("oldpassword");
   var newpassword = document.getElementById("newpassword");
   var cnfpassword = document.getElementById("cnfpassword");

            if (validate_required(oldpassword, "<b>Error: </b>Please enter the Old Password!") == false)
            { changeColor("oldpassword"); return false; }

            else if (valid_length(newpassword, "<b>Error: </b>Please enter the New Password!!") == false)
            {newpassword.value=""; changeColor("newpassword"); return false; }

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some javascript library to get past browser issues. I'm rooting for jQuery.

Comment: can jquery be used for validation as javascript?